# Formatting images for LBP face Recognizer

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I am working on a surveillance project which needs to recognize humans. Currently I have created a interface for collecting the facial data using the LBP face detector. This is what I do in the training phase:

1. Persons need to be seated in front of the camera.
2. Program detects the ROI of his/her face
3. Program saves the ROI as it is.

The program make hundreds of such images for the same person. I want to know whether I need to preprocess the saved ROI images before training the recognizer or give it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You could do either, leave as it is or [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28image_processing%29) the images.

You should find better results with normalization however  you will then also need to normalize your test video